# Will forgetting to call std::ofstream close function lead to memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am just curious about the question: Will forgetting to call std::ofstream  close function lead to memory leak? I give the following example to illustrate my question:

```
using namespace std;
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("C:\\report.html");
myfile << "<html lang=\"en\"> " << endl;
myfile << "<head>" << endl;
```

Normallly, we should also call `myfile.close()` at the end of the code script. However, if I forgot to call the close function, what would happen? Will it lead to memory leak? I have used `memcheck` and `valgrind` in linux to check the program, and no memory leak can be found. So what is the side effect if the close function is not called.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/close/ "Note that any open file is automatically closed when the ofstream object is destroyed."

Comment: The whole point of a destructor is so you don't need to do that sort of thing manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your `std::ofstream` object goes out of scope it will automatically be closed due to the use of `RAII` and the automatic calling of the object destructor.

In this situation your code is perfectly acceptable and would cause no memory leaks. There is no need to call close manually at all.

Only use `close` if you wish to reuse the object before it goes out of scope i.e if the ofstream object was a member of a class and you wish to re-use it then its possible to call `close` on it and then re-open it with a different file etc.

Comment: Thanks, but in which condition calling the close function is mandatory?

Comment: Only if you wish to reuse the object before it goes out of scope i.e if the ofstream object was a member of a class and you wish to re-use it then its possible to call close on it and then re-open it with a different file etc.

Comment: +1.  Could be other scenerios too... on some systems file locking might be a reason to `close` the file "early", and `close` forces a `flush` (as does `endl` which is already used in the code above) and (often usefully) implies that you're not expecting to use the file for a while or again.  Code designed to operate on a variety of streams of which fstream was but one might want to close e.g. remote network connections, pipes etc. as early as possible, so the remote side isn't tied up waiting for further data.

Comment: The last sentence is definitely wrong.  In the normal case, you need to explicitly close the file and check the status after the close; a program that leaves half written files lying around without informing the user is simply broken, and the only way you can avoid this is to explicitly close, then check the status, and inform the user (and delete the file) if there is an error.  (If the close occurs during stack unwinding due to a previous error, and you're going to delete the file anyway, of course it's find to let the destructor do it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze To be fair I was asked in which conditions would you use the close function, not for a complete working example, obviously checking for status etc. is important in a real functioning project(which the original question was not.)

Answer (score 3):

There is none. When the `ofstream` goes out of scope, it will be destroyed, closing it.

Imagine how hard it would be to use a container full of `ofstream`s if you had to make sure to `close` every one before allowing the container to go out of scope.

Comment: But you do anyway, since if any of the close fail, you have to inform the user.

Answer (score 3):

> Will forgetting to call std::ofstream close function lead to memory leak?

Not in your situation: `ofstream` has a destructor, which takes care of cleaning up its resources when `myfile` goes out of scope. This is part of the technique called [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization).

From the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/close/):

> Note that any open file is automatically closed when the `fstream` object is destroyed.

The `close` function is there to let you check if closing the file (or any other stream) has succeeded, and perform some additional file system cleanup in situations when `close` fails.

> I have used memcheck and valgrind in linux to check the program, and no memory leak can be found.

That is a very solid indication that your program does not produce a memory leak.

Comment: Unless you're already in an error situation which will be reported to the user, you must use an explicit close in order to check for errors afterwards.  Not doing so is a programming error.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not call `close` explicitly the file will be closed when the object goes out of scope. So there is no danger of memory or other resource leak.

You may want to call `close` explicitly in order to check if the file closed properly. In many occasions the file will be written to only when it is closed, so checking the stream state after closing may be important.